# How to get value of next iteration in current iteration in Rust for loop?

Tags: for-loop, rust

I have a vector:

```
let mut v: Vec<Vec<i32>> = Vec::new();
// [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5], [12, 13, 14], [5, 6, 7]]`
```

I'm trying to sort it to:

```
// [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [12, 13, 14]]
```

I have to reorganize this vector of vectors by the 'continuation' of each last element. The important thing is I can't change position of elements inside vectors. I can change positions of only whole vectors.

How can I get the value of the next iteration in current iteration?

```
for n in v {
    temp_current_first = n[0];  // OK
    temp_current_last = n[n.len()-1];  // OK
    temp_next_first = n+1[0]; // It's wrong, but something like this
    temp_next_first = n.next()[0] // or this way ??
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> temp_next_first = n+1[0]; // It's wrong, but something like this
> ```

```
temp_next_first = n.next()[0] // or this way ??
```

those 2 don't work because `n` is a simple `i32`, meaning that it does not know that it is part of `v`.

---

In case you only need to look one iteration ahead *(at the next item)*, you could use a [peekable iterator][1], but because you have to scan through the whole vec, this is not what you need here.

---

As far as I understand your question you want to have a kind of chain where one the end of one piece is the same as the start of the next.

```
[4,3][3,7][7,5][5,9] // something like this.
```

I think that it is really complicated to actually do this in a rather quick way.
One way you could do this is the following.

```
fn order<T: PartialEq>(vec: &mut Vec<(T,T)>) {
    if vec.len() == 0 {
        return;
    }

    let mut temp = vec![vec.remove(0)];
           
    'outer: loop {
        let mut next: Option<usize> = None;
        'inner: for (i, item) in vec.iter().enumerate() {
            if item.0 == temp.last().unwrap().1 {
                next = Some(i);
                break 'inner;
            }
        }
            
        match next {
            Some(pos) => temp.push(vec.remove(pos)),
            None => break 'outer,
        }
    }
    *vec = temp;
}
```

Now you could call this function like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<(i32,i32)> = vec![(4,5),(2,8),(5,7)];
    
    order(&mut v);

    println!("{:?}",v);
}
```

This should print: `[(4, 5), (5, 7)]`

---

Let's look at the `order` function in **a lot** more detail:

```
if vec.is_empty() {
    return;
}
```

First we see if `vec` is empty, in this case we just exit the function.

```
let mut temp = vec![vec.remove(0)];
```

We create a new `Vec<(i32,i32)>` which contains the first element of the old vec, which we remove.

```
'outer: loop {
    let mut next: Option<usize> = None;
    
    /* snip */        

    match next {
        Some(pos) => temp.push(vec.remove(pos)),
        None => break 'outer,
    }
}
*vec = temp;
```

Now we create an `Option<usize>` called `next`, if this is zero at the end of the `'outer` loop, there was no fitting element inside of `vec` meaning that we end this function and set the `Vec` we got as input to `temp`.

If `next` is `Some(value)`, it means that we found a fitting pair inside of `vec` which we then remove and `push` into `temp`. After this we just repeat start the loop from the beginning.

```
'inner: for (i, item) in vec.iter().enumerate() {
    if item.0 == temp.last().unwrap().1 {
        next = Some(i);
        break 'inner;
    }
}
```

Here we `iterate` through `vec` and compare `item.0` to the last `element` or `temp`, in case these two are the same we have to somehow remove this `element` from `vec` and put it into `temp`. Sadly we can not mutate `vec` inside of `for`, because the `for`-loop has a reference to `vec`, meaning that we can't change `vec` inside of it.

To circumvent this we simply call `enumerate()` on our `vec.iter()` this tells us the position of the `item` we want to remove. Now, when `if item.0 == temp.last().unwrap().1` is `true`, we set `next` to `Some(i)`(`i` is the position of `item`) and exit the `'inner` loop.

This should explain the function in far more detail than it probably should, hope it helps somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the simplest solution would be to just do:

```
v.sort();
```

Which will only sort the outer vector. Otherwise, if you would like to implement it yourself, I would suggest looking at different [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), as there are **many** possible ways of doing it.

Comment: Thanks @ljedrz I doesn't know that this simple function sort in this way. But what when I'll want to check value of next iteration in current iteration ?

Comment: @twistezo `sort()` uses the `Ord` trait to sort the elements of a slice. `Ord` is also implemented for arrays and will compare lexicographical.